# Is it possible to know what state in TMS workflow the Translation job is

Tags: translation-manager

In Web 8.5, is it possible to know at what state in TMS workflow the job is. We use SDL TMS. We currently subscribe to the Translation Job state changes for some custom functionality we have. But now we want to further be able hook on to the TMS workflow state change?

Answer (score 4):

TM does not have event that fire on every update of item in external translation system.

Only event available "on item retrieve" (ItemRetrieveEventArgs) but it fires only when item actualy retrieved. So only for "Translation Content Retrieval", "Translation Content Retrieval for Preview", "Translation Content Retrieval for Review" steps.

You can always get latest retrieved status of external workflow using API, by loading job and reading **TranslationJobData.WorkflowStatus**

But you have to do it yourself because there is no event for this.

Comment: ItemRetrieve may not work for us as we send bundle of items for translation and the functionality we want to build will trigger for every item. Ability to know the status of the external workflow (TMS) would be ideal. So we can check if that state is reached then do what we want to do which is send notification to the person who initiated the Translation. So, looks like TranslationJobData.WorkflowStatus might help here. Thanks Yuri.

Comment: Besides getting the workflow status, my requirement Yuri here is to be able to hook into the state change of the TMS workflow. Also as per your post I was  loading the TranslationJob details and couldn't find any property like worflowstatus.   We are using the TranslationManagerDomainModel API and have subscribed to the TranslationJobStatechange for other custom implementation. We need a similar implementation for TMS workflow state change

Comment: Looks like  you need to use Tridion.TranslationManagerV2.Data in Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data.dll.   TranslationJobData is there. From there  you can get WorkflowStatus and Workflow Titles.  You can get the Translation Manager API documentation from here:

https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/distributions/?o=6F333A0A-C3FA-4EFC-9986-AC3FCD50243C

Answer (score -1):

If you open the Translation Job within SDL Web and click on the Translation Progress tab, you should be able to see the current TMS workflow state of the translation job.

Edit:

Please take a look at the namespace for more events to setup the custom hook in the SDL Web 8 Translation Manager API docs,(IItemRetrieveEventArgs, IResolvedItemsEventArgs, ITranslationJobStateChangeEventArgs, IQuoteAuthorizationEventArgs )

```
Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.EventSystem.Events
```